# MySQL - Select if the column of every row is TRUE?

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying two tables via a JOIN query to determine if every row in the result set's `approved` column is `TRUE`.

```
SELECT
    `approvals`.`approved`
FROM `sign_ins`
RIGHT JOIN `approvals` ON
    `sign_ins`.`user` = `approvals`.`user`;
```

This will return a result set of boolean values for each user, e.g.

```
1
0
0
1
1
```

My PHP code iterates through these rows and determines if all are approved simply by returning false and breaking a loop if any of these values are `0`. However, I think it would be more performant and optimal if iterating through the result set wasn't necessary; after all, I really only care about one thing: `TRUE` if all the rows' `approved` value are `TRUE`; else, `FALSE`.

Can I do this with a MySQL query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my solution. I use the `MIN` function to select the smallest value, so it should return `0` if there are any `FALSE` values present. Also, since it's not a full join, a sign in that is not present in the `approvals` table should be assumed to be unapproved; therefore, I used `IFNULL` to provide a default `FALSE` value.

Here's a complete example of my query (minus some date logic):

```
SELECT
    MIN(IFNULL(`approvals`.`approved`, FALSE))
FROM `sign_ins`
LEFT JOIN `approvals` ON
    `sign_ins`.`user` = `approvals`.`user`;
```

Answer (score 5):

I would just `COUNT()` all rows and compare that to the `SUM()` of the approved column. If they match, then all rows were 1. If they don't, then there was at least one 0.

Using `COUNT(approved)` will not count `NULL` values, so you don't need to compensate for that.

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(approved)=SUM(approved) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM sign_ins
RIGHT JOIN approvals USING (user)
```

This should return 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want all TRUE results, ask for it!

```
SELECT
    `approvals`.`approved`
FROM `sign_ins`
RIGHT JOIN `approvals` ON
    `sign_ins`.`user` = `approvals`.`user`;
WHERE `approvals`.`approved` = 1
```

Comment: My question is, how can I tell if *all* of the rows are true? I don't want to just select the true ones.